# Can guest users access Power Apps or Power Pages? What are the options available

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, powerapp, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

We have a project that requires guest users to have access to use Power Apps or Power Pages.

My question is do they need to be licensed for them to be able to use it at all.

There are so many resources online but its hard to know the current pathway from Microsoft.

We are happy to use SharePoint list for this project if Guest users can access Power Apps with no licenses.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you going to use standalone canvas apps or Power Apps customized list forms? Canvas apps requires licenses while Power Apps customized SharePoint list forms can work without additional Power Apps license. Let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for your response . In this case we would go Power Apps customized list forms. What about Power Pages?

Comment: Check this: https://powerpages.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the licensing requirements for various types of Power Apps and Power Pages solutions:

1. If you are using the standalone Power Apps canvas apps, guest users will require Power Apps license

   - Microsoft 365 licenses like E1, E3, E5 will work in case you are using standard connectors
   - Power Apps premium licenses will be required if you are using premium or custom connectors
2. If you are using the Power Apps customized SharePoint online list forms with standard connectors, no additional license is required if guest users already have access to SharePoint lists.
3. For Power Pages, Microsoft has separate licensing requirements. Check: [Power Pages pricing](https://powerpages.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/)